# CoreData, recursive structure... I think

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

and thanks for looking...

I'm not even sure how to phrase this question, let alone search for the answer... I have tried, honestly, so all help needed!

It's probably pretty simple as I am sure this is a pattern that happens all the time:

I have an entity in my model (MainLevel*) that has a relationship to itself.

The entity is for levels of a law, and the only requirement is that each law has at least one (the top) level.  Beyond that the number of sublevels is, technically, infinite (but in reality about 5 normally and probably no more than 8-10 at most).  As might be expected each child level has only one parent (MainLevel.parentLevel) and any parent can have multiple (or zero) children (NSSet *childLevels).

What I would like to do is to get all the structure of this relationship to put in a `UITableView` or a collectionView.

I have a recursive function as follows:

```
- (NSDictionary *)getStructureOfLawForLevel:(MainLevel *)level
{
    NSMutableDictionary *mutableDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithCapacity:50];
    MainLevel *currentLevel = level;
    [mutableDict setObject:currentLevel.shortName forKey:@"name"];
    if (level.childLevels) {
        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"order" ascending:YES];
        NSArray *sortdescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];
        NSArray *children = [currentLevel.childLevels sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortdescriptors];
        for (MainLevel *childLevel in children)
        {
            NSDictionary *dict = [self getStructureOfLawForLevel:childLevel];
            [mutableDict setObject:dict forKey:@"sublevels"];
        }
    }
    return [mutableDict copy];
}
```

Then in `viewWillAppear:` I have this:

`self.structure = [self getStructureOfLawForLevel:self.selectedLevel]`

With this I hope I am on the right lines...(untested due to another issue I am sorting right now).

I still cant figure out how to configure a `UITableView` or a `UICollectionView` from this though.  I mean I am sure I can do it by adding a counter or two and getting the number of lines, and sections, that way.  It just seems way, way overcomplicated and I am certain there must be a more obvious method I am just not seeing...

The only criteria for the data is that it must be ordered by the `.order` attribute of the entity instance, and that is not unique.  I mean, for example, each childLevel can have a childLevel with order number 1.  It is the order in THAT parent level.

Sorry if this has been asked a thousand times.  I have tried to search for an answer but nothing seems to fint the search terms I am using.

I am not doing anything with this data except putting on screen, no editing, adding, deleting...  Not sure if that is relevant.

**Edit for clarity...**

I am not looking to do a drill-down type table view.  I want a snapshot of the whole structure in one view, and then I may need to drill down from that (using relationships to other entities in the model).

**EDIT FOR MY SOLUTION**

Here's what I ended up doing...

```
- (NSArray *)getStructureAsArrayForLevel:(MainLevel *)child
{
    NSMutableArray *thisChildAndChildren = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:2];
    [thisChildAndChildren addObject:child];
    if (child.childLevels)
    {
        // children exist
        // sort the children into order
        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"order" ascending:YES];
        NSArray *sortdescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];
        NSArray *children = [child.childLevels sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortdescriptors];
        // get an array for each child via recursion
        for (MainLevel *child in children)
        {
            [thisChildAndChildren addObject:[self getStructureAsArrayForLevel:child]];
        }
    }
    return [thisChildAndChildren copy];
}
```

Then I am using similar recursive function to convert the array to NSAttributedString and display in textView.

I really DO NOT like recursion.  I don't know why but I find it SOOOOOOO hard to get my head around the logic, and when it's done it seems so obvious...  Go figure!

Thanks to everyone for suggestions, help etc...

Comment: Do you want it to all show up in the same table or collection view or show one level and when you tap on that cell it will push you to a new view that shows the children?

Comment: @Bertie Are you looking to build a "drill down" style interface where you would intially see a UITableView with all top level MainLevel objects. Tapping on one would then display a UITableView containing the childLevels of the one you tapped and so on down through the hierarcy. I'm not sure if you are describing this kind of interface or one where the entire hierarchy is displayed in one view.

Comment: I just want to put one 'snapshot' of the entire structure into a view.  I was thinking of putting it into a tableView but I might just design a view to do the same job.  I don't want to drill down through various levels.  Just the whole lot, completely static, on the screen.

Comment: The reason I was looking at a tableview is because there are other relationships (eg to the law articles of each section/level of the law) and I might want to allow the user to view these for any given section/level.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use a 3rd-party controller, take a look at [TLIndexPathTools](https://github.com/wtmoose/TLIndexPathTools). It handles tree structures. For example, try running the [Outline](https://github.com/wtmoose/TLIndexPathTools/blob/master/Examples/Outline/Outline/OutlineTableViewController.m) example project.

Your view controller would look something like this (not much to it):

```
#import "TLTableViewController.h"
@interface TableViewController : TLTableViewController
@end

#import "TableViewController.h"
#import "TLIndexPathTreeItem.h"
@implementation TableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    MainLevel *topLevel = nil;//get the top level object here
    TLIndexPathTreeItem *topItem = [self treeItemForLevel:topLevel depth:0];
    self.indexPathController.dataModel = [[TLTreeDataModel alloc] initWithTreeItems:@[topItem] collapsedNodeIdentifiers:nil];
}

- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // customize cell configuration here
    TLIndexPathTreeItem *item = [self.dataModel itemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    MainLevel *level = item.data;
    cell.textLabel.text = [level description];
}

- (TLIndexPathTreeItem *)treeItemForLevel:(MainLevel *)level depth:(NSInteger)depth
{
    NSMutableArray *childItems = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:50];    
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"order" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortdescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];
    NSArray *children = [level.childLevels sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortdescriptors];
    for (MainLevel *child in children) {
        TLIndexPathTreeItem *childItem = [self treeItemForLevel:child depth:depth + 1];
        [childItems addObject:childItem];
    }
    //set identifier to some unique identifier, if one exists. Otherwise, the item itself
    //will be used as the identifier
    id identifier = nil;
    //set cell identifier based on depth. This can be set to something unique for each
    //depth, or set to a constant value. If nil, the value "Cell" is assumed.
    NSString *cellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%d", depth];
    //pass "level" to the data argument. Or pass any other data, e.g. include the depth @[@(depth), level]
    TLIndexPathTreeItem *item = [[TLIndexPathTreeItem alloc] initWithIdentifier:identifier sectionName:nil cellIdentifier:cellIdentifier data:level andChildItems:children];
    return item;
}

@end
```

You can subclass `TLTreeTableViewController` instead of `TLTableViewController` if you want collapsable levels. Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Thanks for the link, looks interesting and I am going to have a closer look at these when I get a moment.  It seems we just need a plain old textView of the structure for now so have managed to cobble something together per my edit above.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**
Sorry, I missed the part that says you want to display it all at once. Basically, I think the easiest way to do this would be to basically have a recursive structure that gets the description of each object. This could be a string or even a UIView that you could then place inside your tableviewcell.

Lets stick with a dictionary for now. Each dictionary representation can have information about itself and its children. The template can be:

```
<LevelInfoDictionary>
    <NSObject>someObjectThatRepresentsInfoAboutThisLevel
    <NSArray>arrayOfInfoDictionariesThatRepresentChildren
</LevelInfoDictionary>
```

Then to implement your recursive method:

```
- (NSDictionary *)getLevelInfo
{
    NSMutableArray *childInfo = [NSMutableArray array];
    for(ClassName *child in self.children)
    {
         [childInfo addObject:[child getLevelInfo]];
    }
    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         <descriptionOfThisLevel>, @"CurrentLevel",
                         childInfo, @"children>, nil];

}
```

**END EDIT**
Basically, as some of these other guys have said, you should create your tableview that displays all of your top level objects. From there, after you select an object, you should be pushed to a new tableview that uses a different fetch request with the predicate like:

```
 NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"parent = %@",
      selectedParentObject];
```

Then you can use sort descriptors to sort the NSFetchRequest you are using.

Alternatively, you could just fetch the children by using the property on the parent object and store that in an array sorted by your sort descriptors.

One other thing that I should mention is that currently the sort descriptor does not accomplish anything. You may not notice this because there are other parts of the design that you should change, but since an NSDictionary does not have an order (it is a hash table), sorting objects before placing them in a dictionary does nothing.

Comment: Again, thanks for the reply but I really dont need a drill-down table here.  I have a few of those already.  I just need to give the user the entire structure in one shot.  Maybe with the option to expand on things from there.

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer to reflect what you are trying to do. It is somewhat high level psuedocode but thats ok.

Comment: Thanks, I have to eat now...  Will take a look in the morning.  You are right about the sorting though... DOH!  I think I can figure out the whole recursive function thing with a bit of thought (and the ability to test it).  What stopped me was how complicated it seemed to me to set up a tableView section/rows from this.  Maybe on further thought it will be obvious.

Comment: I've used something like this before. It can be complicated and sometimes it is better to go with a simpler design that just pushes a new view when you tap on something, but you could use a library like [this one](https://github.com/gcamp/GCRetractableSectionController) that expands a level to show details about its children when you tap on it. Might be pretty tricky to implement though

Comment: Thanks for the spotting my error with the sorting and then using dictionaries.  I knew I needed an array.  Anyway, managed to solve it as per edits above.

Answer (score 0):

From the ViewController for the TableView or CollectionView you should start by showing all of the top level objects (No parent).  From there as a user selects an object that parent becomes the current level and the ViewController should refresh its data source to show all of the child elements at that level.  You can then traverse back up to the parent via back button.

Let me know if you need any more detail.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear.  I have various methods of drilling down through the levels.  What I want to do is show the user a one-screen snapshot of the whole structure.  As I said to the others, I might want the option to go further from here (which is why I was considering a tableview) as each level/sublevel/childlevel has other relationships I could use here.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop doesn't make sense, because you want a list of the dictionaries for the structure of the children, but what you actually do it to overwrite it each time. You probably want something like:

```
NSMutableArray *subLevels = [NSMutableArray array];

for (MainLevel *childLevel in children)
{
    [subLevels addObject:[self getStructureOfLawForLevel:childLevel]];
}

[mutableDict setObject:subLevels forKey:@"sublevels"];
```

I guess you want to show each level in a table view and drill to another table view for each subsequent level. That should be simple based on the dictionary which gives you a name to display and an optional array which defines whether drilling is possible and the data to pass to the next view controller.

Comment: Hi, Sorry I realise this wasn't clear from the original post, but I really dont want to do the drill-down table thing.  I really just want to put a snapshot of the whole thing on the screen.  I might want to drill down from that but the most important bit is to get the whole outline / structure visible at the same time.

Comment: I am going to have another look at the loop.  You could be right, I have another issue I need to resolve before I can test it.

Comment: Infinite depth isn't going to be easy to show. You could indent, but you'll reach a limit pretty quickly. A bespoke drawn graph makes much more sense (like http://www.graphviz.org/content/siblings). I guess you could do expanding sections, but again showing the depth will be an issue, maybe using colours...

Comment: In reality it isn't infinite.  Might be between 3 and 6 but could be a couple more.  Indenting was never going to be foolproof but I should be OK.  It's really unlikely to go beyond 8.  More than anything, now, I just want to make it work to get my head around it.

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps someone else, here's what I ended up doing...

```
- (NSArray *)getStructureAsArrayForLevel:(MainLevel *)child
{
    NSMutableArray *thisChildAndChildren = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:2];
    [thisChildAndChildren addObject:child];
    if (child.childLevels)
    {
        // children exist
        // sort the children into order
        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"order" ascending:YES];
        NSArray *sortdescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];
        NSArray *children = [child.childLevels sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortdescriptors];
        // get an array for each child via recursion
        for (MainLevel *child in children)
        {
            [thisChildAndChildren addObject:[self getStructureAsArrayForLevel:child]];
        }
    }
    return [thisChildAndChildren copy];
}
```

Then I am using similar recursive function to convert the array to NSAttributedString and display in textView.

I really DO NOT like recursion. I don't know why but I find it SOOOOOOO hard to get my head around the logic, and when it's done it seems so obvious... Go figure!

Thanks to everyone for suggestions, help etc...

**EDIT**

It isn't exactly right, as the first layer has a slightly different structure to those that follow.  at some point I need to change this to have the top level as a directory and use the very first level as the key for the directory, then add the complete array as the object for that key.  But it works... my brain aches... and I can live with it until I get around to changing it.